# Who Guarantees the Accuracy of a Smart Contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Assume Client A wants to sell a package to client B.

Comment: i am just posting this for general reference

Comment: What do you mean by accuracy here? What are your criterias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s return for a moment to the idea of the blockchain. “The [Bitcoin] blockchain is an incorruptible digital ledger of economic transactions that can be programmed to record not just financial transactions but virtually everything of value.”  Blockchain operates in a trustless environment where multiple parties on a network have open and easy access to information. This potentially leaves the information vulnerable; however, Bitcoin’s blockchain implementation employs a distributed network, hash codes, and cryptographic keys that create an immutable record where tampering is easily detected. This is why blockchain operates well in a trustless environment. Parties to a Bitcoin transaction don’t need to trust each other. The Bitcoin blockchain documents the transaction, period.

So once a smart contract is posted in a blockchain, it is an immutable record where tampering is easily detected. That’s not what we’re talking about here. We’re talking about what happens when the smart contract is being developed before it’s posted to the blockchain and how we would know the smart contract represents the actual verbal or written agreement between the parties, and their intentions.

Comment: Did you notice it was the Ethereum StackExchange site?